# how to add single quotes to string in c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am adding mutliple values  to single string  , all the values should be like in this format `'',''` but I am getting `"'',''"` instead.

How can I remove these double qoutes? Here's the code I'm using:

```
string one = "\'"+ names[0, 0] +"\'"+","+"\'" + names[1, 0]+"\'";
string[] splitted = one.Split('\'');
string ones = "'" + splitted[1] + "'" +","+ "'" + splitted[3] + "'";
```

Comment: Have you tried using `string.Format` for building the strings? It could make your code a lot easier to read.

Comment: Maybe dumb question: are you sure the `"` are actually part of your string, and not just displayed in the debugger?

Comment: Are you sure the the `"` is not exist after the split ?

Comment: Your code works as is. Of course I assume the values in names doesn't contain a single quote. Right?

Comment: Rawling is right... If you are newbie for Visual Studio, might be u were trying to see the values during debugging. Don't worry your actual string won't contain double quotes ""

Comment: @Rawling ,In string its coming fine ,wen i debugging the javascript actually i am getting string like "'',''" but i need it like "''","''" .

Comment: @GAPS above values are recieving fine those vaues am sending to javascript it should only in single qoutes.but for me its reciving "'value1','value2'"

Comment: where is your `javascript` code then...@user1619151

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to escape single quote like `"\'"` instead you can simply use `"'"`, so you code should be:

```
string one = "'" + names[0, 0] + "'" + "," + "'" + names[1, 0] + "'";
string[] splitted = one.Split('\'');
string ones = "'" + splitted[1] + "'" + "," + "'" + splitted[3] + "'";
```

Comment: same thing even i have done ,in string it was coming fine actualley i am passing to javascript its automatically adding double quotes.

Comment: Why do single quote escapes even exist in C# if all strings are double quoted?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I fully understand, but there are two ways.

Output:  `".","."`

```
var s1 = @"""."","".""";
var s2 = "\".\",\".\"";
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to encapsualte escape sequences and special characters within a string is the use of webatim character.

e.g.

```
String escSeq = "C:\\MyDocuments\\Movie";
```

can also be stored as:

```
string escSeq = @"C:\MyDocumens\Movie";
```

The @ character you must put before the string starts and outside the "" characters.

Answer (score 0):

I just worked with your code..it works just fine..

Debugger will show: `"'val1','val2'"`

Actual Value  : `'val1','val2'`

From the debugger point you will see `"'val1','val2'"` but actually it happens for every `string` values. but actually when you prints the value in a page you will see the actual value as `'val1','val2'`

EDIT:

For sending those values to javascript what you can do is just set those values in `Hidden fields` and then fetch those value from that using `document.getElementById('hidden_field')`.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
        var values = document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value;
        alert(values);
        var tweetUsers = [values];

        var buildString = "";

Comment: I am getting only for one value if i am giving multiple values its not working ,please give me some solution.

Comment: I am declaring string while debugging it as to come like "''","''" or else '','', but its coming like "'',''" , please check out my code  for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
                {


                    names[i, 0] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();

                }

                string one = "\'" +names[0, 0] + "\'" + "," + "\'" + names[1, 0] + "\'";
                string[] splitted = one.Split('\'');
                string onces = "'" + splitted[1] + "'" + "," + "'" + splitted[3] + "'";
                "string".Replace(@"\", "'");


                inpHide.Value = onces;

Comment: It still giving `"'val1','val2'"` in debugger but `'val1','val2'` in javascript...

Comment: @ Vishal Suthar Your right  if i keep alert box its showing only the values , but the thing is data is not recieving.its showing empty box.